# How to get the last value from a model list without looping it in MVC?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i need to get the last value from a model list in a view without looping it..Here is my controller code

```
public IList<ProductDetailModel> GetWPDetails()
            {
                ProductDetailModel Viewmodel;
                string funname = "GetCSpecialWPDetails";
                List<ProductDetailModel> getWPDetails = new List<ProductDetailModel>();
                getWPDetails = objrest.EcommerceWPDetails(funname);
                List<ProductDetailModel> WPDetails = new List<ProductDetailModel>();

                foreach (var item in getWPDetails)
                {
                    Viewmodel = new ProductDetailModel();
                    Viewmodel.Productid = item.Productid;
                    Viewmodel.ProductName = item.ProductName;
                    Viewmodel.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                    Viewmodel.ProductRate = item.ProductRate;
                    Viewmodel.DiscountRate = item.DiscountRate;
                    Viewmodel.imageurl1 = item.imageurl1;
                    WPDetails.Add(Viewmodel);
                }
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ThemeColor,LayoutDesign FROM dbo.Cpecial_Partner_Design WHERE [PartnerID]='" + Partid + "'", con);
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        Viewmodel = new ProductDetailModel();
                        Viewmodel.ThemeColor = myReader["ThemeColor"].ToString();
                        Viewmodel.LayoutDesign = myReader["LayoutDesign"].ToString();
                        WPDetails.Add(Viewmodel);
                    }

                    myReader.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
                return WPDetails;

            }
```

and here in view i am getting the values by looping the model and the total count is 47 but what i need is i need the 47th value alone that is the last value alone without any looping.

View code

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ThemeColor)
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.LayoutDesign)
       }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you mean "without having to write code for iterating it". =) You could try `.Last()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use linq! In your case [.Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) method.

Try:

```
@{ var last = Model.Last(); }
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => last.ThemeColor)
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => last.LayoutDesign)
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for null. If you're always expecting a result, you might as well use `Last()`. =)

Comment: @Mateusz: This could potentially lead to `NullReferenceException` when there are no items in the collection so you have to check against nulls but yes, +1 from me, as this is the simplest approach.

Comment: Don't use `...OrDefault` if you don't check for `null`. Use the normal extensions (`First`, `Single`, `Last`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems to be an IList<>, so I'd suggest simply using this:

```
var last;
if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0) last = Model[Model.Count - 1];
else
...
```